# Cómo iterar por grupos

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente lista que se repiten los elementos:

```py
numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Podría usar un contador como:

```py
def contador():
   numero = 0
   while True:
      numero += 1
      yield numero
```

Pero necesito ayuda sobre cómo podría crear un programa que se dé cuenta de las repeticiones de los elementos por grupo de la lista y me los dividida en listas independientes.

Muchas gracias

Comment: No pareces estar contando nada. La función `contador` es un generador, es igual que decir `range(n)` para algún valor de n.

Comment: @CandidMoe que codigos puedo usar?

Comment: Tipicamente para contar cosas usas un diccionario. La llave es la cosa (un entero de la lista, en este caso); en el valor vas acumulando la cuenta. Algo asi como `totales[entero] += 1` por cada entero que vas extrayendo de la lista.

Comment: Quizás te interesa usar un objeto [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).